# Proper location to declare SQLite getWritableDatabase()

Tags: java, android, sqlite

It says not to call it in the oncreate, but that aside: how can I make it globally accessible? If I have several functions that access the database, how would I efficiently use the single instance of it, rather than re-call the write function in every function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you should call it each time you need a database instance for new operations. It's not your task to cache its instance... Jut remember to call close().

Answer (score 0):

IMHO First port of call is an SQLLiteOpenHelper subclass:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

> A helper class to manage database creation and version management.
>
> You create a subclass implementing onCreate(SQLiteDatabase),
>   onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and optionally
>   onOpen(SQLiteDatabase), and this class takes care of opening the
>   database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and upgrading it as
>   necessary. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always
>   in a sensible state.